# Reading Google Sheets from PHP

Tags: google-sheets-api

For the past 2 years, I have used https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbygukdW3tt8sCPcFDlkMnMuNu9bH5fpt7bKV50p2bM/exec?id=SheetID&sheet=Sheet1 to read Google Sheets data vis PHP.

As of Thursday, June 14, that method as returned an error "Authorization is required to perform that action.".

What do we do now?  I contacted the GitHub author within a half-hour.

This was a simple, useful method.  There might be other methods, more complex?

Comment: It seems that the URL in your question is the endpoint of Web Apps. I think that it is required to authorize the scopes of the Web Apps script again. If the Web Apps is yours, please redeploy and authorize again. If the Web Apps is other users, please tell the owner to authorize the Web Apps again. If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: This blog provides an alternative. http://pipetree.com/qmacro/blog/2013/10/04/sheetasjson-google-spreadsheet-data-as-json/

I know how to use the macro, however, I would like to learn know how to write such a script as the macro calls, and I would like to learn how to set up scripts/macros in my Google "myaccount".

Comment: I'm really sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: You were kind to add your comment.